# Flutter sqfLite , SELECT DISTINCT not working

Tags: flutter, sqflite

My rawQuery SELECT DISTINCT... not working in flutter sqflite.

This is quiz like app and I have series of questions from db, user answer yes /no and I save index number in sherePref,
latter from method   _getAnswer() I get those numbers and pass to the getList method from DB.
I get results Details and Output  but SELECT DISTINCT not working I get all answers and duplicates..

My method from dataBase:

```
  Future<List<List<Widget>>> getList(List<int> list, String column) async {
    List<Widget> list1 = List();
    List<Widget> list2 = List();
    List<Widget> list3 = List();
    List<List<Widget>> listFromDB = [list1, list2, list3];
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, 'books.db');
    Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var result = await database
          .rawQuery('SELECT DISTINCT $column FROM $booksTable WHERE $colId= ${list[i]}');

      debugPrint('List: ' +list[i].toString());
      if (list[i] < 18) list1.add(_item(result[0][column].toString()));
      if (list[i] > 17 && list[i] < 50)
        list2.add(_item(result[0][column].toString()));
      if (list[i] > 49) list3.add(_item(result[0][column].toString()));
    }

   // await database.close();
    return listFromDB;
  }
```

```
 bool _summary = false;

  _getAnswer() async{
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> listString = pref.getStringList('Answers') ?? List();

    if(listString.isNotEmpty){
      List<int> listInt = listString.map(int.parse).toList();
      listInt.sort();
      _list = await DB().getList(listInt, _summary ? 'Detail' : 'Output'); //colums from db.

      setState((){});
    }
  }
```

What im doing wrong? I want to colums Detail and Otput be free of duplicates.

Comment: what is the *exact* value of `var result` you are getting in each loop iteration?

Comment: var result = await database
          .rawQuery('SELECT DISTINCT $column FROM $booksTable WHERE $colId= ${list[i]}'); .    Im getting first 17 results (that is first set of questions) from $column (whatever column i pass there. so that part is working, but no DISTINCT

Comment: what is the **exact** value of `var result` you are getting in each loop iteration? is `result` a list that has the same values? if so what is the exact value of that list?

Comment: Its not same values but some are duplicated, i see the problem is how to DISTINCT two colums at same time..

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Title FROM books WHERE Color="RED" ---working, all titles without duplicates with color RED return.
SELECT DISTINCT Title,Subtitle FROM books WHERE Color="RED" ---not working all titles return with duplicates return.

Comment: Im gona try different thing now, to remove duplicate from list,

Comment: import 'package:queries/collections.dart';

void main() {
  List<String> list = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "d"];
  var result = new Collection(list).distinct();
  print(result.toList());
}

Comment: Do you know how to convert that var result back to list?